# Unity 4.5 Mesh Collider Not Interacting with Circle or Box Collider 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unity3d-2dtools

I am new to unity and I am working on a 2D game. Currently, I am having trouble getting two colliders to interact when one of them is a mesh collider and the other is a box or circle collider. I was originally working to get the Unity Sample Assets 2D character to interact with a mesh terrain. When I "played" the game, the circle collider attached to the legs of the character was falling through the mesh terrain. I have simplified the problem and created two cubes:

- One cube I upload and keep the 2d box collider and add a rigid body to
- The second cube I delete the 2d box collider and add a mesh collider

I place the second cube under the first cube and hit "play". The top cube falls through the bottom box. When I replace the bottom cube's mesh collider with a box collider and hit "play" it correctly collides and stops on the box. I'm guessing I'm making the same mistake in this simplified example as I am in the more complicated 2D Character scenario. Do you have any suggestions of what I am doing wrong? I have tried making the mesh collider convex (although I believe this should only be necessary between two mesh colliders?). I have also ensured that the z position is the same as well as the layers of the two objects.

Comment: I think I have found the issue. I think the problem is that the mesh is a 3D collider which cannot interact with 2D colliders. When I change it to 3d box colliders it interacts properly with the mesh collider. Is this correct?

Comment: There is a difference between a 2D game (e.g. based on sprites and 2D-based positions and physics) and a "game that looks 2D" (but uses the 3D engine) , you shouldn't try to combine those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot collide a 3D object against a 2D.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) 
{
    // Code here is clueless about 3D.
}
```

[API Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html).

> Sent when an incoming collider makes contact with this object's
>   collider (2D physics only).

You could cheat a little. Before Unity had 2D colliders what people would do is create a very thin box collider3D, which in your case should work.

Comment: I would need to change the rest of the physics2D objects attached to the character as physics 3d objects in order to do this right? Or is there some other way I can add a 3D collider?